# 'parse error' when trying to install apk on devices below minimum sdk

Tags: android, sdk, android-manifest

When I try to install apk on devices whose sdk level is less than what is mentioned in manifest, I get Parse error message. My question is, is there a way through which we can show a custom message to the user? For example: this app requires min android version to be ICS or something like that.

Comment: seems to me like this issue is happening before the app is installed, meaning it's a system error, there for you have no power on it and can't modify it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Just put it in your androidmanifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

---

then inside onCreate you can check the sdk version as bellow:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

and show a dialog telling the user that this app requires min android version to be ICS
then finish the application !

Comment: how is this answering the question?!

Comment: Theoretically this is the only possible solution to achieve what he wants, after you do the check you should kick out the user out of the app before you call any api in ICS+. And you should also disable lint check about the API level.

However, this is a really bad solution to have coz this will let the users give your app a very low rate and uninstall the app once they discover that the app is really for upper android versions.